# C# MVC Como usar formato moneda

Tags: c#, mvc

**Necesito usar el formato moneda**

Al usar la anotación:

(Model)

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public Nullable<float> monto { get; set; }
```

(View)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.monto_observado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Muestra correctamente el dato pasa editar:

```
$26,281,000.00
```

pero al intentar "Guardar" me valida

> The field Monto Observado must be a number.

**Que tengo que hacer para poder usar formato moneda?**

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741233/) a ver si te sirve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es porque al momento de convertirlo a formato moneda el tipo de dato ya no es un `float`, es un `string`. Tienes que retirar todo lo que no sea número para que lo pueda tomar al momento que se lo asignes en su modelo.

Función en js para desenmascarar formatos de tipo dinero:

```
function unmaskDinero(dinero) {
    return Number(dinero.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
}
```

Y lo asignas con unmaskDinero

```
model.monto_observado = unmaskDinero(monto$);
```

Comment: Para que la respuesta quede completa, solo faltaría que le indiques al OP la forma de invocarla

Comment: en que momento puedo asignar al modelo?

model.monto_observado = unmaskDinero(monto$);

Comment: Puedes crear un modelo espejo en javascript, manteniedo los nombres y tipo de datos, y utilizarlo tal como tu modelo en c#. Pero depende de como estés trabajando con ellos, como eso corresponde a otro ámbito de la pregunta te puedo apoyar en un chat.

Comment: estoy iniciando en este sitio, no se como hacer un chat, pero te agraezco mucho el codigo que me proporcionaste, fue de mucha ayuda para mi solución.
sabes si tengo que cerrar la pregunta o algo así?

Answer (score 2):

Mi Solución

(Model)

```js
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]

[DataType(DataType.Currency), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public Nullable<double> monto { get; set; }
```

(View)

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "enviar" }))
{
    
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.monto_observado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.monto_observado,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.monto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="button" id="guardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

(script)

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#guardar").click(function () {            
            
            //igual se pueden validar mas controles

            currency = $("#monto_observado").val();
            $("#monto_observado").val(unmaskDinero(currency));
            
            $("#enviar").submit();
        });
    });

    function unmaskDinero(dinero) {
        return Number(dinero.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    }

</script>
```

(Concluiones)

el modelo muestra los numeros como indica DisplayFormat tanto la lista como al editar despues de editar, al hacer clic en el botón de enviar, lo formatea como un numero decimal y envía a controlador para guardar los datos.

agradeazco a Pikoh, así como Aaron Romero su valiosa ayuda.